# How to do Sql server procedure using parameters like where @para1 = @para2

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

I have a procedure with a single select statement. I am need to create some 50 procedures like the one below..

```
create procedure foo1 as 
select cityid, cityname from footballteam
```

the **footballteam** will be common in all my procedures, Instead of creating 50 single procedures, I want to code like below and send 3 parameters from my c# page

```
create procedure foo1 (@id bigint, @name varchar(50), @param bigint)as 
select @id, @name from footballtem where @id =@param
```

can i pass like this in sql server ?/ How to do like this

will I am able to do **procedure overloading** in sql server, some time I need to pass only two parameters and i want to get a particular value , I will pass three or more parameters ....

Answer (score 2):

For a pure TSQL answer:

```
create table footballtem(id int identity(1,1),cityid int, cityname varchar(50))
go
insert footballtem(cityid, cityname) values (123, 'abc')
insert footballtem(cityid, cityname) values (456, 'def')
go
create procedure foo1 (@id sysname, @name sysname, @param bigint) as
declare @sql nvarchar(100) = 'select ' + QUOTENAME(@id) + ','
       + QUOTENAME(@name) + ' from footballtem where '
       + QUOTENAME(@id) + '=@param'
exec sp_ExecuteSql @sql, N'@param bigint', @param
go
exec foo1 'cityid','cityname',123
```

(credit is due to [Mikael Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569436/mikael-eriksson) re `QUOTENAME`)

Note that `QUOTENAME` makes the `@name` and `@id` injection safe.

Note also, though, that the *varying* parameter (`@param`) is safe from injection - we don't need to validate that anywhere; and that this will allow query-plan re-use via `sp_ExecuteSql`

Comment: I guess you could use `quotename(@id)` and `quotename(@name)` to take care of SQL-injection problems.

Comment: @Mikael - ooh, nice. I tend to avoid this scenario in the first place, but that is a good fix for that issue

Comment: Looks good to me. And credits should really go here http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html :)

Comment: you are still returning a complete recordset when all the OP needs and wants is two parameter values (and really only needs one).

Comment: @CosCallis er, no... it returns 2 columns (as per the example), and is filtered on the rows (as per the example)

Comment: @Marc, It can't "just return two columns". There is a lot more going on in the data stream to support those two columns.

Comment: @Marc, looked at code just like a thousand times. I also understand the object model in play. The columns you SEE are wrapped in a lot bits that you don't. There are only two things that can come back from an SQL query, Record Sets and Parameters (a return value is a parameter). One Row, two Columns, still a recordset.

Comment: @Cos - ah, by "complete recordset", I assumed you meant no horizontal or vertical filtering. The OPs example seems to indicate that they are after more than one row, IMO. It could *probably* be tweaked to use `OUT` params if really needed, but frankly: that is not going to be a bottleneck.

Comment: @Marc, I absolutely agree. The "performance metric" between the two is _minimal_. The way I read the OP's example he is wanting a single row (but I found the example hard to follow on in places...) which I always steer toward parameters over records.

Answer (score 1):

No; that would do a comparison on the parameter values, and return the parameter values. To do that, you would have to substitute the values at the caller, for example:

```
string idColumn = "id", nameColumn = "name";
string tsql = string.Format(@"
create procedure foo1 (@param bigint)
as select [{0}], [{1}] from footballtem where [{0}]=@param", idColumn,nameColumn);
```

and have 50 SPs; you *can* do the same in TSQL, using sp_ExecuteSQL against an already replaced string, but IMO it would be better to do this at the app tier than inside the database.

Also; question whether you really need stored procedures... that one isn't really going to help much; a parameterised TSQL query is much simpler, just as fast, and easier to deploy.

Comment: You mean creating the procedure itself in c# ? Do you really do that. Is that safe enough. ? and I dont think use of place holders is a good method to supply parameters .

Comment: @nandu.com - the *parameter* (`@param`) is not substituted at all. But for the rest - *you have to* ; you can't parameterise the actual query itself - only the, er, parameters. As for creating it in C# - you yourself added the C# tag ;p Ultimately, it won't matter *how* you create them; personally I wouldn't create them *at all* - I'd just use a parameterised query. I'd need a good reason to create a proc for that.

Comment: @nandu.com  specifically, you could do the same thing in TSQL and use sp_ExecuteSQL to invoke it, but by the time you've done that you might as well have not used the stored procedure in the first place - simpler just to execute a parameterised query.

Comment: We are following a standard in our team, to use select statements as procedure and not as tsql queries. So I need procedure only

Answer (score 0):

I think you were asking for the following:

```
create procedure foo1 (@id bitint out, @name bigint out, @param bigint)
as
select @id=cityid, @name=cityname from footballteam where teamname = @param
```

But your question makes it seem like you are trying to dynamically change the column names per query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can specify a default value for a stored procedure parameter in T-SQL. So you can omit it while calling.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1 @param1 int, @param2 int = -1 AS SELECT case when @param2=-1 then somefield else @param2 end as column from sometable where somekeyfield=@param1; GO
```

Answer (score 0):

(*assuming MS SQL Server*)

MS SQL server does not support procedure overloading (as Oracle Does) but does support input and output parameters like this:

```
create procedure foo1 (
     @param bigint
    , @id bigint out
    , @name varchar(50) out

   )as 

select 
 @id = fbt.id
,@name = fbt.name 
from 
   footballteam fbt 
where fbt.id =@param
```

@id and @name have to be passed in as null value output paramters of the correct type. After execution (cmd.executeNonQuery) you can inspect the command object to get the new parameter values back out.

I am not sure I am reading your question correctly, but if I am then this should get what you want..

**Adding better code sample after question **

```
//_assumes the following using statements at the top of code file:_
//using System.Data;
//using System.Data.SqlClient;
     public string getTeam(int CityID)
          {
             string name;

             using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("foo1",new SqlConnection("myConnectionStringGoesHere")))
             {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param", CityID));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.BigInt){Direction=ParameterDirection.Output});
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar,50) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output });

                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                name = cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value.ToString();

                cmd.Connection.Close();

             }

             return name;
          }
```

Comment: Execute non query will only return no of rows affected. How can I get the dataset out of it ? Can u explain ?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery with only _return_ the number of rows, yes. However the command maintains the reference to the parameter objects which are updated with the values as a result of the execution of the stored procedure. It is about holding references to pointers and not values.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do overloading on MSSQL. Here how it goes:

For example we have a sp_Personel procedure which takes personel type as parameter and lists personel of that type.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Personel]
           @PersonelType int
AS
SELECT Name, JoinDate, PersonelType, Salary
FROM Personel
WHERE PersonelType = @PersonelType
END
```

Now, you want another procedure which will be for personel join dates.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Personel];2
           @JoinDate datetime
AS
SELECT Name, JoinDate, PersonelType, Salary
FROM Personel
WHERE JoinDate <= @JoinDate 
END
```

To call second procedure from management studio;

```
[dbo].[sp_Personel];2 N'9/26/2010'
```